# How can I find out if ProGuard has been successful in obfuscating an Android APK?

Tags: android, google-play

I have typed `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` and renamed `keepclasseswithmembernames` to `keepclasseswithmembers` and it has successfully exported signed `.apk`.
How to find out if proguard was successful in obfuscating the code?

Am I missing something or is it good to go to market?

This thread should not be limited to source code suggestions. ANY and ALL suggestions about posting an app to the android market would be appreciated by not only me, but any other nooobs that might be posting their first app to the market and researching this topic on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the `proguard` folder :  You will see files like `mapping.txt`, `dump.txt`, `usage.txt` etc. Also if you look in the `logcat` you will see that `Class` names and `Method` names are `obfuscated`.

[image]

For more details go [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Another hardcore way will be to use [`dex2jar`](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [`java decompiler`](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) to decompile your app and see how much you'll suceed. If `obfuscation` went well you'll see that it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks its visible in my project so is the app good to go to market?

Comment: Yes, I think so. To be sure you can try the hardcore way.

Comment: Hello Binoy there is no progaurd.jar and unoptimized.jar but rest of the files are visible .Is it Alright?

Comment: In `mapping.txt` can you see stuff like     `android.os.AsyncTask task -> a
    int cacheSize -> b
    int dataSize -> c
    int systemSize -> d
    java.lang.String vsDesc -> e` etc?

Comment: There is no AsyncTask but it has org.json.JSONObject json -> a
    java.util.ArrayList mapOverlays -> v

Comment: Then it's obfuscated. Congrats. :)

Answer (score 3):

ProGuard will run when you build your app in Release mode. You can tell it successfully obfuscated the code if the following files are generated

- dump.txt
- mapping.txt
- seeds.txt
- usage.txt

The location of these files are:

```
<project_root>/bin/proguard if you are using Ant.
<project_root>/proguard if you are using Eclipse.
```

For more details and to learn about the contents of these files look at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thanks Its visible so Have I done everything correct? Can I upload it to market now??

Answer (score 0):

Convert apk to jar and extract it. if you see file names are not changed proguard not affect on code

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Use this gradle task. This gradle task will allow you to automate the detection of files as mentioned by Binoy Babu and monkybonk05. This needs no visual inspection. Your build will fail if the files don't exist. Generally proguarding in done on the release version of the application

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleFlavorRelease') {
        task.finalizedBy checkProguardFlavor
    }
}
task checkProguardFlavor << {
    assert file("./build/outputs/mapping/Flavor/release/dump.txt").exists()
    assert file("./build/outputs/mapping/Flavor/release/mapping.txt").exists()
}
```

Comment: Please be sure to always add a description as to how your code resolves the issue. please review [answer]